# How to cancel an edit to an object using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

How can I implement cancelation of editing an object using MVVM.

For example: I have a list of customers. I choose one customer an click the button "Edit", a dialog window(DataContext is binded to CustomerViewModel) opens and I start editing customer's fields. And then I decide to cancel editing, but the fields of the customer have been already changed, so how can I return a customer to its previous state in MVVM?

Answer (score 13):

Check out the [`IEditableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) interface. Your `Customer` class should implement that, and your commands can execute `BeginEdit` / `CancelEdit` / `EndEdit` as appropriate.

Comment: IEditableObject creates a lot of overhead for your objects, especially if your Model objects are a Class and not a Struct, you would have to rewrite your model objects to support it.

Comment: @Agies: Why the downvote? Whether IEditableObject is a "lot of overhead" or not depends entirely on your infrastructure or how you want to implement it. It's just an interface that WPF understands. How you implement it is up to you.

Comment: +1, yes, I want to implement it with IEditableObject, but I have a ViewModelBase<TModel> which exposes a property Model of type TModel and I bind the View directly to the properties of the exposed model. Now how could I still use 'Cancel Edit', also, now that you know my scenario, say that my TModel is an Address entity. in view mode it's just binds to the FullAddress line and uses the AddressDataTemplate (making a link to GMaps), but I want that when the user clicks the Edit button on the AddressView, it should open a ChildWindow (SL, or whatever Window in WPF) to be continued...

Comment: ...continued: and this ChildWindow should display the TextBoxes for editing the fields of the Address, and it should have a Save and **Cancel** button, so I can cancel the edits, now it's basically 2 questions, 1) the OPs question; how to cancel the changed fields of the entity to the original fields 2) how do I call up the editing window to popup from the AddressViewModel when edit starts? please refer me to a good link.

Answer (score 5):

You can use binding with `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`. [Here](http://kvelikov.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/edit-with-explicit-updatesourcetrigger/) you can find more information how this can be implemented.

Comment: Good answer should be more specific, best if it includes code example.

Comment: Although this answer is lacking detail, I think it is the cleanest solution.  UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit is made exactly for what terkri is trying to do.  The other solutions, while they may work, are really just hacks.

Comment: If your validation relies on tracking source changes (via `IDataErrorInfo` for example) then you won't get validation until you update the source (if at all, I'm not sure), at which point you may still want to be able to roll back all changes but your model will already have updated.

Answer (score 4):

One super easy way, if your object is already serializable, such as if you are using WCF. You can serialize your original object into an internal field. If, your object isn't serializable, then just use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to create a copy of your object with one line of code.

```
Order backup = Mapper.Map<Order, Order>(order);
```

When you handle your CancelCommand, just call AutoMapper in reverse. Since your properties already have a change notification everything just works. Its possible you could combine these techniques with IEditableObject, if you need and want to write the extra code.

Comment: The down side to AutoMapper is that it only captures state that is reflected through the Properties. So like other solutions that assume that every piece of state for each editable class is exposed through read/write properties, this should work fine for scenarios that use DTOs or other similar anemic objects but in the case where there they are rich domain objects there may be no properties at all. Binary serialization and NetDataContractSerialization don't have this problem since they work with fields. BTW, it's tricky when events and delegates come into play.

Answer (score 3):

In [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVMAdventuresWPF.aspx?display=Print), Raul just reload the object from the DB. I guess it's less trouble than the solution Kent proposes.

```
    internal void Cancel(CustomerWorkspaceViewModel cvm)
    {
        Mainardi.Model.ObjectMapping.Individual dc = cvm.DataContext 
                                 as Mainardi.Model.ObjectMapping.Individual;

        int index = 0;

        if (dc.ContactID > 0 && dc.CustomerID > 0)
        {
            index = _customerCollectionViewModel.List.IndexOf(dc);
            _customerCollectionViewModel.List[index] = 
                                  _customerBAL.GetCustomerById(dc.CustomerID);
        }

        Collection.Remove(cvm);
    }
```

Comment: I think reloading from the DB is one way of fulfilling the obligations of the IEditableObject of mr Boogaarts suggestion, not necessarily an alternative to the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Камен Великов's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17957183/479330):

You can mark your bindings as to be updated manually by defining

`<TextBox Name="yourTextBox" Text="{BindingPath=YourBinding, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />`

in your view (XAML).  Then, you have to write the changes from your UI in ViewModel by calling

`yourTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();`
when Save is clicked.

Please note, if there are updated to the binding source triggered from anything else, they are still shown directly in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I solved it using "The Memento Pattern Design". With this pattern you could easy save a copy of your original object and, in `selectedIndexChange` (of a control) or in the Cancel button, you could restore easy the prior version of your object.

An example of use of this pattern is available at [How is the Memento Pattern implemented in C#4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994433/how-is-the-memento-pattern-implemented-in-c4)

An example of code:

If we have a class User with properties UserName Password and NombrePersona we need to add methods CreateMemento and SetMemento:

```
 public class Usuario : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region "Implementación InotifyPropertyChanged"

    internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    private String _UserName = "Capture su UserName";

    public String UserName
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
        set { _UserName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("UserName"); }
    }

    private String _Password = "Capture su contraseña";

    public String Password
    {
        get { return _Password; }
        set { _Password = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Password"); }
    }

    private String _NombrePersona = "Capture su nombre";

    public String NombrePersona
    {
        get { return _NombrePersona; }
        set { _NombrePersona = value; RaisePropertyChanged("NombrePersona"); }
    }

    // Creates memento 
    public Memento CreateMemento()
    {
        return (new Memento(this));
    }

    // Restores original state
    public void SetMemento(Memento memento)
    {
        this.UserName memento.State.UserName ;
        this.Password = memento.State.Password ;
        this.NombrePersona = memento.State.NombrePersona;
    }
```

Then, we need a class Memento that will contain the "copy" of our object like this:

```
 /// <summary>
/// The 'Memento' class
/// </summary>
public class Memento
{
    //private Usuario _UsuarioMemento;
    private Usuario UsuarioMemento { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public Memento(Usuario state)
    {
        this.UsuarioMemento = new Usuario();

        this.State.UserName = state.UserName ;
        this.State.Password = state.Password ;
        this.State.NombrePersona = state.NombrePersona ;
    }

    // Gets or sets state
    public Usuario State
    {
        get { return UsuarioMemento; }
    }
}
```

And we need a class that will generate and contains our memento object:

```
/// <summary>
/// The 'Caretaker' class
/// </summary>
class Caretaker
{
    private Memento _memento;

    // Gets or sets memento
    public Memento Memento
    {
        set { _memento = value; }
        get { return _memento; }
    }

}
```

Then for implement this *pattern* we have to create an instance of `Caretaker` class

```
Caretaker creadorMemento = new Caretaker();
```

And create our memento object when a new user was selected for edit, for example in `selectedIndexChange` after the SelectedUser has been initializing, I use the method for event `RaisPropertyChanged` like this:

```
internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
        if (prop == "RowIndexSelected") // This is my property assigned to SelectedIndex property of my DataGrid
        {
            if ((this.UserSelected != null) && (creadorMemento .Memento != null))
            {
                this.UserSelected.SetMemento(creadorMemento .Memento);
            }
        }
        if (prop == "UserSelected") // Property UserSelected changed and if not is null we create the Memento Object
        {
            if (this.UserSelected != null)
                creadorMemento .Memento = new Memento(this.UserSelected);
        }
    }
```

An explication for this, when `selectedIndexChanged` change value we check if `UserSelected` and `our memento object` are not null means that our actual item in edit mode has changed then we have to Restore our object with the method `SetMemento`.
And if our `UserSelected` property change and is not null we "Create our Memento Object" that we will use when the edit was cancel.

For finish, we have use the `SetMemento` method in every method that we need to cancel the edition, and when the edit has commited like in the SaveCommand we can set null our memento object like this `this.creadorMemento = null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also, in your ViewModel copy the model's state to internal fields, and then expose these and then only set them on the model, when the user actually commits the change.

Problem could be, that on-the-fly validation will be more troublesome if validation relies on the entity being updated - if this is a requirement you could create a clone of the model to work on and then merging the clone with the actual entity when it is saved.