# ObservableCollection does not update

Tags: wpf, binding

I have `ObservableCollection<Customer>` on my window.

```
ObservableCollection<Customer> customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get { return customers; } set { customers = value; OnPropertyChanged("Customers"); } }
```

This `ObservableCollection` has bound to `ListView` on the window. Once Use select on Customer   from `listView` and click on edit a new window will appear with selected customer's data.

**Second window's constructor**

```
public EditCustomerWindow(Customer c)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    customerobj = c; //Original object
    tempCustomerobj = new Customer(c); //Getting a copy of the customer object

    CustomerDataGrid.DataContext = tempCustomerobj;
}
```

Once user clicks on **Save Button** customer object will get updated and window will closes.

But my issue is `ObserverCollection` does not get update on fist window even though I set new edited customer object before editing window get closed. Cannot find what is the wrong I am doing. Please advice me.

```
customerobj = tempCustomerobj;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be creating a *new* Customer object that is not in your *ObservableCollection*

```
tempCustomerobj = new Customer(c);
```

and then editing that *new* object.

```
CustomerDataGrid.DataContext = tempCustomerobj;
```

Doing that will not in any way affect the original Customer object that is still in your *ObservableCollection*.

To solve, don't create a *new* Customer, but rather edit an existing one.

**Update**

*Based on your comments*

The line

```
customerobj = c; //Original object
```

causes `customerobj` to be an alias to `c`, your object that is actually in the `ObservableCollection`.

The line

```
customerobj = tempCustomerobj;
```

causes `customerobj` to now be an alias to `tempCustomerobj`, which is your brand-new Customer object that is (I presume) a *clone* of `c`.

Change your constructor to

```
public EditCustomerWindow(Customer c)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CustomerDataGrid.DataContext = c;
}
```

**Update 2**

The object you're editing should support IEditableObject. See

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091240/141172

Alternatively, you can serialize the object before you start editing and deserialize the saved state if the edit is canceled.

Comment: That is why I am assigning  `customerobj = tempCustomerobj;` to reflect the changes before leaving the window. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong.  The symbol *customerobj* is an *alias* to whatever actual object you currently have assigned to it.  Given your code, you should just assign *c* to the *DataContext* and not use *customerobj* or *tempCustomerobj* at all.

Comment: Reason for why I did not do that is; If I assign `c` to `DataContext` ObservableCollection will get updated even though user cancel the edit after changing some fields values.

Comment: The object you're editing should support IEditableObject.  See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1091240/141172.  Alternatively, you can serialize the object before you start editing and deserialize the saved state if the edit is canceled.

Comment: If you can edit your answer with previous comment I can mark your answer as accepted. :). thanks for the guidance.