# MVVM way to close document with possibility to cancel out

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, avalondock

I'm using Avalondock 2.x for one of my open source projects, if a document is dirty when you close it you should be able to cancel the close.

I am using Caliburn Micro and Coroutine, only way I have been able to solve it is to use C.M to attach to the event

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="DocumentClosing">
    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="DocumentClosing">
        <cal:Parameter Value="$documentcontext" />
        <cal:Parameter Value="$eventArgs" />
    </cal:ActionMessage>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

The event arg has a cancel property. Problem with this approuch is thats its not very MVVM friendly, I have created a little helper method to Coroutinify this like

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> Coroutinify(IEnumerable<IResult> results, System.Action cancelCallback)
{
    return results.Select(r =>
        {
            if (r is CancelResult)
                cancelCallback();

            return r;
        });
}
```

Used like

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> DocumentClosing(ScriptEditorViewModel document, DocumentClosingEventArgs e)
{
    return Result.Coroutinify(HandleScriptClosing(document), () => e.Cancel = true);
}
```

This works but it's a bit clumsy etc, is there a more MVVM way of closing documents in Avalondock with cancel ability?

**edit: source code**

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.GUI/Shells/MainShellView.xaml#L29

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.GUI/Shells/MainShellViewModel.cs#L110

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.GUI/Result/ResultFactory.cs#L49

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cancel an edit to an object using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091036/how-to-cancel-an-edit-to-an-object-using-mvvm)

Answer (score 4):

The way I've accomplished this is by binding to the **CloseCommand** property of an AvalonDock LayoutItem. When this binding is associated, it overrides the default behavior of closing a document ('X' button, right click close / close all). You then are fully responsible for removing (closing) the document if desired.

The way I set it up was to have a DocumentManagerVM which contains an ObservableCollection of DocumentVMs. Each DocumentVM has an ICommand called RequestCloseCommand, which can close the document by removing itself from the collection of DocumentVMs it's owning DocumentManagerVM.

Specifically, in my DocumentVM viewmodel, there's an ICommand (I'm using mvvmLight RelayCommand) to perform the closing logic:

```
public RelayCommand RequestCloseCommand { get; private set; }
void RequestClose()
{
    // if you want to prevent the document closing, just return from this function
    // otherwise, close it by removing it from the collection of DocumentVMs
    this.DocumentManagerVM.DocumentVMs.Remove(this);
}
```

In your view, set up your binding in the LayoutItemContainerStyle or LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector.

```
<ad:DockingManager
    DataContext="{Binding DocumentManagerVM}"
    DocumentsSource="{Binding DocumentVMs}">

    <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ad:LayoutItem}">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.RequestCloseCommand}"/>
        </Style>
    </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>

</ad:DockingManager>
```

Comment: I've tried to find info how to use Caliburn Micro Coroutine together with Command properties but havent found a good way

Comment: @Anders What if your command resides in DocumentManagerVM.  The following doesn't work.  I've been starting at LayoutItemContainerStyle doc.  {Binding DataContext.RequestCloseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource, Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ad:DockingManager}}}

Answer (score 0):

I added a Dependency Property to the DockingManger, that allows binding to a Close Command:

```
public static class DocumentClosingBehavior
{
    #region Dependecy Property
    private static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentClosingCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
                (
                    "DocumentClosingCommand",
                    typeof(ICommand),
                    typeof(DocumentClosingBehavior),
                    new PropertyMetadata(DocumentClosingCommandPropertyChangedCallBack)
                );
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public static void SetDocumentClosingCommand(this UIElement inUIElement, ICommand inCommand)
    {
        inUIElement.SetValue(DocumentClosingCommandProperty, inCommand);
    }

    private static ICommand GetDocumentClosingCommand(UIElement inUIElement)
    {
        return (ICommand)inUIElement.GetValue(DocumentClosingCommandProperty);
    }
    #endregion

    #region CallBack Method
    private static void DocumentClosingCommandPropertyChangedCallBack(DependencyObject inDependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs inEventArgs)
    {
        DockingManager uiElement = inDependencyObject as DockingManager;
        if (null == uiElement) return;

        uiElement.DocumentClosing += (sender, args) =>
        {
            GetDocumentClosingCommand(uiElement).Execute(args);
        };
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In XAML:

```
<xcad:DockingManager vm:DocumentClosingBehavior.DocumentClosingCommand="{Binding DocumentCloseCommand}" Grid.Row="2" 
                       AllowMixedOrientation="True"
                       BorderBrush="Black"
                       BorderThickness="1"
                       Theme="{Binding ElementName=_themeCombo, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"
                       DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                       ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ActiveDocumentConverter}}"
                       >
```

In my MainViewModel I define an ICommand DocumentCloseCommand.